# Codeigniter Invalid Login Return

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to return some error message, if the user's email and password is not stored in database,  codeigniter validation error messages are running without any errors. But i can't pass my validation message, the error parameter to view. I'm getting Undefined variable: error message instead.

Here is what i've done :

Controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){
        if($this->user_m->login() == TRUE){
            redirect($dashboard);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Wrong email, password combination.');
            $error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
            $data['error'] = $error;
            redirect('admin/user/login','refresh');
        }
    }
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
    $this->load->view('admin/layout',$this->data);
```

View:

```
<?php if($error){ ?>
        <div id="error_text"><?=$error;?></div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="error_text"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?></div>
```

And controller:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE){
        if($this->user_m->login() == TRUE){
            redirect($dashboard);
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Wrong email, password combination.');
            redirect('admin/user/login','refresh');
        }
    }
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/login';
    $this->load->view('admin/layout',$this->data);
```

Comment: thank you, this has worked, but isset is false here, giving php error. with removing that, code works fine.

Comment: Ok, I edit the answer for others that have the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$this->load->view('admin/layout',$this->data);`

should be

`$this->load->view('admin/layout',$data);`

or

change the error variable:

`$data['error'] = $error;`

into

`$this->data['error'] = $error;`